# Making a concatenated list of zipcodes in a compressed dataset in SAS

Tags: sas

I need to create a zipcodes variable that combines the string variable "zip" in a concatenated list of the zipcodes for each city. Here's what I have so far:

```
data work.zip (drop=estimated_population zip);
    set work.clean;
    by state primary_city;
    length zipcodes $200;
    retain zipcodes;
    if first.primary_city then do;
    estcitpop=0;
    zipcodes= zip;
    end;
    else
    zipcodes=cats(zipcodes, ',', zip);
    estcitpop+estimated_population;
    if last.primary_city;
run;
```

This gets me the right result, but is there a better way to do it?

Zips are character values and need to stay that way. If, for example, for the city of Houston, you have zips 12345, 11345, 11145, and 11115, I need zipcodes to read "12345,11345,11145,11115".

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine.  I would use `CATX()` function and a DOW loop to make it simpler.

```
data work.zip ;
  do until (last.primary_city);
    set work.clean;
    by state primary_city;
    length zipcodes $200;
    zipcodes=catx(',',zipcodes, zip);
    estcitpop=sum(estcitpop,estimated_population);
  end;
  drop estimated_population zip;
run;
```